# CSS to delete elements only for AMP posts

Tags: css

What CSS can I use to delete elements only for AMP posts on the website? [AMP](https://amp.dev/) is an open-source framework, which reduces page size and eliminates javascript, so that website loading times could are less than 1 second.
I know how to hide an element is with `display: none` .
But I don't know how to implement that only on AMP posts.
This is the class of elements I want to remove only from the AMP post: `lwptoc_toggle_label` .
Class: `lwptoc_toggle_label` .
I have written the CSS `.lwptoc_toggle_label {display: none}` so that the element is removed, but the problem is I don't know how to apply that CSS only to AMP posts.
Can I use this: `@media screen and (max-width:480px) {.lwptoc_toggle_label {display: none!important}}` ?
Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Hi. Please post some code.

Comment: CSS can't do CRUD operations like deleting a DOM element. You need to use some programming language like javascript to do that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CRUD operations, @m.popov

Comment: Ok, I've written the code in my question @VidiyaPrasanth

Comment: @MushlihAlmubarak When you talk about Create, read, update, or in your case delete, you talk about a CRUD operation. that's why I wrote the comment above.

Comment: @MushlihAlmubarak since I think you are talking about hiding not deleting If your AMP post has a unique class or id you can use that identifier to target the "lwptoc_toggle_label" selector. something like .uinique-class .lwptoc_toggle_label {display:none}. If you can share a link to your website or show a full code snippet of a normal post compared to that AMP post I can be more helpful. Also please, clarify, what is an "AMP" post.

Comment: @m.popov I didn't create a unique class. [AMP](https://amp.dev/) is an open-source framework, which reduces page size and eliminates javascript, so that website loading times could are less than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

CSS is an adjective-like language, it is not functional.

JavaScript is the event-driven verb-like language. You need to put `script` elements inside of the `head` element if you plan to code professionally or you can just dump it at the bottom of the `body` element if you don't care about professionalism.

```
<script defer="true" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

// Put JavaScript code here, like the code below.

//]]>
</script>
```

## Use Examples

You can then use the unique `id` attribute to reference an element you want to delete or use other methods of selecting an element. That reference becomes a `parameter` when calling the `element_del` function.

- `element_del('test12');//Instead of document.getElementById('test12')`
- `element_del(document.getElementById('test15'));`
- `element_del(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[4]);`

## Function

This is the function we use for an entire web platform. We don't use frameworks or libraries because you don't get paid for maintaining poor code.

```
function element_del(id)
{
 if (typeof id=='string' && document.getElementById((id) && document.getElementById((id).parentNode.removeChild)
 {
  document.getElementById((id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById((id));
 }
 else if (typeof id=='object' && typeof id.parentNode=='object')
 {
  id.parentNode.removeChild(id);
 }
}
```

Comment: However, javascript won't work on AMP posts, is there another way?

Comment: The only thing you can do is change `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` or change other aspects such as `position: absolute; left: -40000px` or `margin-left: 50000px`. You could also try `height: 0px; width: 0px;`.

Comment: No, I've tried it but it doesn't work, Can I use this: `@media screen and (max-width:480px) {.lwptoc_toggle_label {display: none!important}}` ?